# How to separate two dates from one columns - Read from external file

Tags: java, arrays, date, date-parsing, dateinterval

So far I have been able to read from an external excel file which has two columns.

**ID    Date**
1   12/12/2018 13/12/2018
2   12/12/2018 13/12/2018
3   12/12/2018 13/12/2018
4   12/12/2018 13/12/2018
5   12/12/2018 13/12/2018
6   12/12/2018 13/12/2018
7   12/12/2018 13/12/2018

My question is, is there any way possible to split that one column which contains two dates into another column or separate it in different method perhaps? The above is a prototype, the answer method will be used on big data. Any help will be highly appreicated, please.

Code used so far:

```
package readexcel;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;


public class Readexcel{

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unchecked" })
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

//
// An excel file name. You can create a file name with a full
// path information.
//
String filename = "C:\\filepath...xls";

//
// Create an ArrayList to store the data read from excel sheet.
//
List sheetData = new ArrayList();
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
//
// Create a FileInputStream that will be use to read the
// excel file.
//
fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

//
// Create an excel workbook from the file system.
//
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
//
// Get the first sheet on the workbook.
//
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

//
// When we have a sheet object in hand we can iterator on
// each sheet's rows and on each row's cells. We store the
// data read on an ArrayList so that we can printed the
// content of the excel to the console.
//
Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
while (rows.hasNext()) {
HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

List data = new ArrayList();
while (cells.hasNext()) {
HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
data.add(cell);
}

sheetData.add(data);
}
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
if (fis != null) {
fis.close();
}
}

showExcelData(sheetData);
}

private static void showExcelData(List sheetData) {
//
// Iterates the data and print it out to the console.
//
for (int i = 0; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
List list = (List) sheetData.get(i);
for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
Cell cell = (Cell) list.get(j);
if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
} else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
} else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
}
if (j < list.size() - 1) {
System.out.print(", ");
}
}
System.out.println("");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Are the two dates separated by a single whitespace?

Comment: Yes they are most of the times

Comment: Other examples of dates: 12/12/2018-13/12/2018 and sometimes 12/12/2018 - 13/12/2018

Comment: One suggestion is: use a regular expression like `(\d+/\d+/\d+)\D+(\d+/\d+/\d+)` for taking out the two dates, then parse each into a `LocalDate` for validation.

Comment: Are you trying to create another Excel file, or do you want just to split the string? There's `split()` method for that.

Comment: Trying to split them and If I could put them in new .txt file or even a new excel file that would be even more helpful. But they need to be matching the correct ID. I will look into Split now also, cheers

Comment: @Ole V.V. I will have a look into that now. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Pattern twoDates = Pattern.compile("(\\d+/\\d+/\\d+)\\W+(\\d+/\\d+/\\d+)");
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/u");

    String[] dateStrings = {
            "12/12/2018 13/12/2018",
            "12/12/2018-13/12/2018",
            "12/12/2018 - 13/12/2018"
    };
    for (String dateString : dateStrings) {
        Matcher m = twoDates.matcher(dateString);
        if (m.matches()) {
            try {
                String ds1 = m.group(1);
                LocalDate ld1 = LocalDate.parse(ds1, dateFormatter);
                String ds2 = m.group(2);
                LocalDate ld2 = LocalDate.parse(ds2, dateFormatter);
                System.out.println("First date: " + ld1 + " Second date: " + ld2);
            } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
                System.out.println("Invalid date in string " + dateString
                        + ": " + dtpe.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not two dates: " + dateString);
        }
    }
```

This outputs:

```
First date: 2018-12-12 Second date: 2018-12-13
First date: 2018-12-12 Second date: 2018-12-13
First date: 2018-12-12 Second date: 2018-12-13
```

I first use a regular expression to pick out the two dates from the string. Next I want to use `LocalDate.parse` for parsing and validating the dates. You may want to add a range check for further validation. If so, use `LocalDate.isBefore` and/or `.isAfter`.